# itun.es URL shortener syntax

Tags: iphone, itunes, url-shortener

I'm about to release an iPhone app. Part of its functionality is that the user can send some content of the app by email (amazing!).

Now, by default, I'm inserting some text in the body of the newly composed message, including a link to the App Store, enabling the person who receives the message to download my app (revolutionary!).

So, I figured out, that the URL of an app is:

> `http://itunes.apple.com/app/id[your apple app id here]`

which is very convenient, because you can actually include the url in your app, even before the app actually exists. (Your apple app id is indicated in itunesconnect).

But, I want this to even look better, by using the [recently introduced itun.es URL shortening protocol](http://www.everythingicafe.com/itunes-gets-its-own-url-shortener-for-twitter/2010/12/11/).

I don't know nor understand too much about URL Shorteners. I just want to be able to express an iTunes link of a not yet existing app that already has an ID in an itun.es way.

Does anybody know the algorithm?

Comment: wouldn't it look even better if you linked to your own website? ie: download.youapp.com ?

Comment: Maybe, but even then I would like to put the itun.es link on my own web site...

Comment: Curious about this myself, as I have in fact seen examples in the wild.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know of any quick way to do it, but it is possible. The clumsy way to extract it is to go to the app in the iTunes app store and choose "Share on Twitter" from the dropdown menu next to the price. This will open a link in your browser. The itun.es URL is in the query string of the link, though it's URL-encoded and initially difficult to see. For example, here's the link for the iPad Pages app:

http://twitter.com/#!/login?redirect_after_login=%2Fhome%3Fstatus%3DApple%25C2%25AE%2B-%2BPages%2B-%2Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fitun.es%252Fi6M97N%2B%2523iTunes

The shortened app identifier is just after "itun.es%252F", beginning with "i" and continuing up to the next percent sign. Pages has the identifier "i6M97N", so the final URL is just:

http://itun.es/i6M97N

Comment: This is true. However, the question was for an unreleased app. Is there a way to get the URL before the app is available on iTunes (i.e. just in iTunesConnect)?

Comment: I doubt it. The app identifiers in the full URLs appear to be related to date of release in the store, so it seems unlikely the short URL would be available before release. Still, filing a feature request with Apple might eventually get you what you want.

Comment: You can view the iTunes URL before the app is released if you go to http://developer.apple.com --> iTunes Connect --> Click on you unreleased app --> Click on "View in App Store". iTunes will try to open the link but then say "App is not available in this store".

Answer (score 5):

To find the itun.es and appsto.re an app

1. Open up the app in the Desktop version of iTunes.
2. Next to the "Download" button, click the arrow, then click "Share on Twitter".
3. You'll get a link that resembles https://appsto.re/xxxxxxx in the tweet box.

To get the itun.es link just take the url and replace the domain with itun.es. So you will end up with:

https://appsto.re/xxxxxxx and https://itun.es/xxxxxxx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to get the short URL **before** the app is released.